# php://input returning empty string

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, zend-server-ce

The following code recently started returning empty strings.  It works on other systems, so it doesn't appear to be a problem with the code itself.  I literally eliminated all of the server-side code, and it still did the same thing.  I also tried using file_get_contents to no avail, just kind of shooting in the dark.

```
$fileStream = fopen('php://input', 'rb');

$fileData = '';
while ($buffer = fread($fileStream, 4096)) {
    $fileData .= $buffer;
}
```

**Server:** Zend Server 5.1.0 (Apache 2.2.3)

**Language:** PHP 5.3.5

**Front-End:** Plupload (JavaScript plugin)

Comment: Did you try using `STDIN` in place of `$fileStream` (and dropping the first line)?

Comment: "I literally eliminated all of the server-side code" Is this in a server-side or command-line program?

Comment: It's in a web application (no CLI for this feature).

Comment: `php://input` cannot be opened/read when receiving a `multipart/form-data` POST, maybe that's what changed client-sided?

Comment: @Wrikken That's was exactly the issue.  Thanks so much for your help!  You saved me many hours of troubleshooting!

Comment: Nice to know. If you need this functionality, you might be able to destroy the multi-part header with [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html), haven't tested it, but the only reason PHP normally doesn't let you read this is just a memory / optimization issue in the PHP core itself, not a real technical limitation / impossibility. I've seen a working answer somewhere on SO, but can't seem to find it right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `php://input` cannot be opened/read when
>   receiving a `multipart/form-data` POST,
>   maybe that's what changed
>   client-sided? – Wrikken Mar 28 at
>   20:01

Thanks for your help!